# Override jQuery event itself, not the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, overriding

I want to override the jQuery resize event with the debounced smartresize function of http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

How can I use the debounce function when binding on `resize`, not explicitly `smartresize`?

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    alert('test')
});
```

Should go through the `debounce` function of the URL above.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest a simpler way to apply debounce, jquery itself has it own function:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    $.debounce( 250, function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use this. I'm asking because I have a library that listens on `$(window).resize` but I want it to listen on `$(window).smartresize` without having to touch it and destroy update compatibility. So I have to change `$(window).resize` to have the same effect as `$(window).smartresize`, with your suggested code this unfortunately does not work.